# Jenkins pipeline: docker.withServer(...) does not execute docker commands on remote server

Tags: docker, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I'm using Docker Pipeline Plugin version 1.10. 
I have my Jenkins installed in a container. I have a remote server that runs a Docker daemon. The daemon is reachable from the Jenkins machine via TCP (tested). I disabled TLS security on the Docker daemon.
I'm not able to make the docker.withServer(...) step work.
As a basic test I simply put following content in a Jenkinsfile (if I'm correct this is a valid pipeline content):

```
docker.withServer('tcp://my.docker.host:2345') {
  def myImage = docker.build('myImage')
}
```

When the pipeline executes I get this error: ***script.sh: line 2: docker: command not found*** like the docker command was still trying to execute locally (there is no docker command installed locally) rather than on my remote Docker daemon.

Am I missing anything ? Is it required to have the docker command installed locally when trying to execute Docker commands on a remote server..?

Answer (score 1):

have you tried

```
withDockerServer('tcp://my.docker.host:2345') {
   .....
}
```

Documentation [here](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/docker-workflow/#withdockerserver-sets-up-docker-server-endpoint)

Comment: `withDockerServer(..)` is called by the [`withServer(...)`](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker-workflow-plugin/blob/master/src/main/resources/org/jenkinsci/plugins/docker/workflow/Docker.groovy#L44) function so I think that call it directly would not change anything.

Comment: In fact from what I have seen in [Docker.groovy](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker-workflow-plugin/blob/master/src/main/resources/org/jenkinsci/plugins/docker/workflow/Docker.groovy) it seems that the docker commands are executed directly using the available _docker_ command installed on the agent. So using `withServer('tcp://my.docker.host:2345')` would simply add the option `-H 'tcp://my.docker.host:2345'` to the command you execute which means that you still need docker installed on your agent when you want to execute docker commands on a remote server...

Comment: I found much of what was out on the web to be misleading. As of Aug 2017, I was not able to get docker in Jenkins:2.73 working without installing docker directly into the container. Ultimately, I followed this guide: http://verbally.flimzy.com/installing-docker-1-12-debian-9-stretch/ to install docker 12 into the official/community maintained container at https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker/blob/master/README.md.

Afterward, I was able use the 'withDockerServer' and have it call out to docker on the other server.

Comment: Here is my code:
https://github.com/cognitiaclaeves/docker-jenkins2-dkr

Answer (score 0):

`docker` needs to be installed on jenkins master in order for jenkins to be able to launch the docker on `my.docker.host`.

- the first `docker` command runs on jenkins master, but with a parameter to pass the command to `my.docker.host`
- the container itself will then run on `my.docker.host`

Note that you only need to install `docker` on the jenkins master; the daemon does not need to be running on jenkins master.

Comment: we need to use docker daemon from remote, not local docker.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have set up port correctly. Default port for daemon is 2375. It has to be checked on both docker daemon (option -H 0.0.0.0:2375) and on the jenkins client